# CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I just started to get this error this morning. I cant build any of my projects since then. Any solutions how to fix this? Tried `Clean Project` and `Invalidate Caches and Restart` multiple times. It worked until today.

Found some question about exact same problem that it can be caused by Windows filepath length. All my projects are located in `D:\AndroidProjects` folder. It is not long path.

This error is sometimes replaced by `Error running 'app': Default Activity not found`

UPDATE:
Error is still appearing more frequently now. I just have to try and build the project 20 times in a row and out of nowhere it is working 21nd time. This is some bug in recent Android Studio update. Other coworkers having same problem on Windows and macOS.

Its something with java path:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the only solution worked for me.

1. Close Android Studio
2. Kill all "java" processes in task manager (You may skip this step if you assume that all "java" processes were closed)
3. Manually delete your project's "build" folder. (Usually the path is "YourProjectFolder\app\build")

I know this is temporary, but this is reliable, so saves our time.

[Note: <strike>I noticed that it happens if we don't restart our computer for long time. I usually hibernate/resume. That may be the root cause.</strike>
It happens even if we restart daily. :(
]

Answer (score -4):

**You should have at least one activity that looks something like this:**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.your.package.name.YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

---

### if this not working for you then apply File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart once again

Comment: My app is 3 years already in development. I have everything set up correctly. It worked for 3 years :) These issues came as I updated from Android Studio 3.5 to 4.0 2 weeks ago and it keeps poping up from time to time. Clearly some problems on their side.

Comment: don't know why you facing this type of error, in fact most of error like yours  happend becuase of activity not decliaring in menifist or declared more then one activity as launch activity or may be you use same name for class and activity... please remove your down vote otherwise I will not able to comment more please...